# liblinear memory cost too much

Tags: python, machine-learning, liblinear

I have run the liblinear to modeling a model file.

The python code is here:

```
y, x = svm_read_problem(vector_file)
prob = problem(y, x)
param = parameter('-s 2 -c 1')
m = train(prob, param)
save_model(model_file, m)
```

The problem is that when the vector_file is about 247MB, the total cost of memory when running  liblinear is about 3.08GB. Why does it cost so much?

And In my project, the vector_file will be as large as 2GB, how can I use liblinear to train the problem, then I can get a model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I know why the problem is.

When read the problem, the python interface of liblinear use:

```
prob_y = []
prob_x = []

for line in open(data_file_name):
    line = line.split(None, 1)
    # In case an instance with all zero features
    if len(line) == 1: line += ['']
    label, features = line
    xi = {}
    for e in features.split():
        ind, val = e.split(":")
        xi[int(ind)] = float(val)
    prob_y += [float(label)]
    prob_x += [xi]

return (prob_y, prob_x)
```

In python,  int costs 28 bytes and float costs 24 bytes, which is out of my imagination.

I will post such cases to the author.